# Newbie DIY hobbyist wanting to try out ROS

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Newbie wanting to try out ROS from zero as DIY hobbyist and EE/CS student with Ubuntu, hardware and C experience. I have read posting with search keyword of ‘hobby, Learn’ in this forum. I have zero ROS knowledge.

NO need for PRECISE answer. Just comments from your (or your students') past personal experience in learning ROS from zero. My question is, it will take ???? weeks to get to the levels of  ‘something working’ on screen, on device and on ‘real’ platform. Or, re-phase the question, will 1 to 2 day per week over 3 months be a reasonable time frame?

Understand ROS is complex and used in university research. In this context,‘Something working’ means hobby level of able to interface sensor (like ultrasonic range sensor on servo sweeping 180 degree), able to form a map of the room and able to command the robot to move toward exit (using simple logic of moving toward the direction with longest clear path)

a)  ???? weeks to learn basic ROS with SLAM, Navigation and Mission Planning

b)  ???? weeks to test/learn writing device driver for a new sensor (ultrasonic sensor, send via RS232 0x50 to trigger it. It replies with 2 bytes for distance in mm)

c)  ???? weeks to port the above to a simple home-made (DIY hobby style) low-cost motor platform. That is, already have DC motor, wheels and H bridge driver hardware mounted on plastic board for existing Arduino simple robot. Hi/Lo pins for motor direction and on/off. PWM duty cycle to control speed. Photo interruptor feedback for actual wheel displacement.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51227/newbie-diy-hobbyist-wanting-to-try-out-ros/) by [ROS123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3867/ros123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Obiously there cannot be a straight numerical answer to our questions, as the time to success largely depends on your current skills and the time you can invest.

I suggest you spend a day or an afternoon doing the core ROS tutorials, and other tutorials that seem of interest to you, like mapping and navigation tutorials. After that day you should be able to judge yourself how much time you can expect to require.

However you could also ask another question where yo give more details on the hardware specs of your target DIY platform and sensor, to find people working on similar platforms who can share tips or code with you.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-02**:
A good resource is the Home Brew Robotics Club http://www.hbrobotics.org